# No route matches [POST] "/articles/new" - Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made the following introduction:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And after that, I wanted to create a new field (like title) and got the error notification:

Here is my code:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    resources :description
    root 'welcome#index'

    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  end
end
```

I know that this question has been asked a lot but their solutions didn't helped me.

What should I do?

Regards

Comment: Show your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: You'll need to add more detail in order for people to help with this. For instance was everything working correctly until you started making a change to add the new field? If so, describe the changes you made. Also when does this error appear?

Comment: Here's the file
<code>
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

   resources :articles do
   resources :comments
   resources :description

  root 'welcome#index' 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
end
</code>
And I did changed the new.html.erb file. I added a new f.label and f.textarea

Comment: @neverbesuccesfulllperson How are you trying to crate the new field? Did you add a button in your `index.html.erb`? If so, show that code; also show `new.html.erb` code.

Comment: index.html:
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titel</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
 
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>

Comment: new.html:
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Titel %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Kommentar %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>


   <p>
    <%= f.label :Beschreibung  %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

 
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

Comment: It's better to add the code (with proper format) in your question; just click "edit" and add new code.

Comment: I edited your question to ad `routes.rb`, use that as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `new.html.erb` form, you are missing `url: articles_path`, if you don't specify it, the form will be sent to the same action (i.e. `new`). So, since submitting the form uses `POST` (by default) method, you get:

> No route matches [POST] “/articles/new”

You need to change your `form_for` and specify the `url`, like this:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

From the [same link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form) your provided:

> There's one problem with this form though. If you inspect the HTML
>   that is generated, by viewing the source of the page, you will see
>   that **the action attribute for the form is pointing at /articles/new**<sup>1</sup>.
>   This is a problem because this route goes to the very page that you're
>   on right at the moment, and that route should only be used to display
>   the form for a new article.

<sup>1</sup> *My emphasis*.

Answer (score 0):

By default rails new resource route has a `GET` HTTP verb, not `POST`. Unless you specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `new_article_path` or `articles/new` in the form

```
<%= form_for :article, url: new_articles_path do |f| %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```